# Using private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Reports.class); print log on console but no file created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j

Im using `private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Reports.class);`

This is my log4j config file:-

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to server home/omoto/
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/user/performance_logs/performance.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I'm printing log using logger like :-

```
logger.info("Reports.java handleRequest(..) is strated!");
```

My problem is the log gets printed in console but no file is generated at the specified path present in properties file.

I have looked through many solutions but those did'nt solve my problem.

Is there anything here that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are the permissions correct?

Comment: Is your path name correct? That is, did you mean `/home/user/performance_logs/performance.log` or did you mean `/home/omoto/...`. Either way, do you have permission to write to that directory and/or file?

Comment: Ensure that your code not imports java.util.logging.Logger, rather than org.apache.log4j.Logger and you have permissions required

Comment: Actually the problem was the log4j files it was picking from activemq-all-5.14.3.jar, so after replacing import statement to org.apache.log4j.Logger[log4j.jar] it solved the problem, Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use,

```
 `private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Reports.class);`
```

As well as, you need to implement below dependency, if you are working on spring boot maven project,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>

            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```